Managing False Discovery Rate in feature selection with grouped features and non-normal correlation p-values
I'm developing a model to explain the revenue growth of firms within an industry using various economic time series indicators, such as the labor employment index and inventory index. After applying transformations to achieve stationarity, I end up with several hundred features organized into related groups. My goal is to reduce the number of features before generating feature combinations for model input.
When I read up on this topic, the problem of false discovery rate/multiple comparison comes up, and it is suggested that I use multiple test correction methods, such as those available in statsmodels' multipletests, to address the issue.
I attempted to apply these corrections to the p-values derived from Pearson correlations between each feature and the target variable. I have the following questions regarding this approach:

Assumptions of Pearson Correlation P-Values: The p-values obtained from Pearson correlations are based on the assumption that the variables are drawn from independent normal distributions with a population correlation of zero (as stated in the scipy.stats.pearsonr documentation). This assumption may not hold true in my case. How should I address this discrepancy when performing multiple test corrections?

Applying Corrections Within Feature Groups: Since my features are naturally divided into distinct groups, is it appropriate to apply the multiple test correction procedure within each group separately? My objective is to retain at least one significant feature from each group. Would this approach effectively control the FDR, or are there better strategies for grouped feature selection?


